# Rest API stop working due to "minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService"

Tags: sharepoint-server, administration, installation, configuration, server-farm

I am working on an on-premise SharepPint 2013. and the site collections are working well. but on a specific screen i wrote a javaScript will call the Restful API for a list. and this script was not working correctly. so i tried to access the REST API using my browser and i got this error:-

> Memory gates checking failed because the free memory (141824000 bytes)
>   is less than 5% of total memory. As a result, the service will not be
>   available for incoming requests. To resolve this, either reduce the
>   load on the machine or adjust the value of
>   minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService on the
>   serviceHostingEnvironment config element.

[image]

so can anyone adivce on this please? again the site collections are working fine,, and i am able to view/edit/delete items. but the problem is happening on the REST API.

So can anyone adivce on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue occurs if the available memory on the web server is low So

- Try to restart `Sharepoint search host controller` in windows service to release all the leaked memory and consumed memory !
- Or scale up your memory.
- Also, check the following links to adjust `minFreeMemoryPercentageToActiveService` Configuration Setting as a permanent  solution.

  - [Mitigation: minFreeMemoryPercentageToActiveService Configuration Setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn458357(v=vs.110).aspx)
  - [SharePoint Memory gates checking failed because the free memory is less than 5% of total memory.](https://sureshunakka87.wordpress.com/2016/02/22/sharepoint-memory-gates-checking-failed-because-the-free-memory-is-less-than-5-of-total-memory/)

Comment: thanks for the links ,, but none of them have mentioned if there is any risk if i minimize the "_minFreeMemoryPercentageToActiveService_" to be less than 5 ?? could this result in a server hangs? i mean there should be a reason why it is  set to 5 by defualt ,,although inside the message i got seems MS suggested to minimize the number  "_to resolve this, either reduce the load on the machine or adjust the value of minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService on the serviceHostingEnvironment config element._" ?

Comment: Microsoft set it by default 5 as a recommended value because it didn't know your current memory specification at web server so I have mentioned the above other solutions before changing minFreeMemoryPercentageToActiveService because it will effect on the memory size that will be consumed by web service meanwhile it improves system stability by preventing the OutOfMemoryException exceptions, so to avoid this Try to restart Sharepoint search host controller in windows service to release all the leaked memory and consumed memory or scale up your memory.

Comment: i already restart the whole server,, but the problem is happening,, now i checked the CPU using Task Manager and it is always above 90% ... so i disable contentious crawl as a test ,, but before modifying the "_minFreeMemoryPercentageToActiveService_" to 2 , i am trying to understand  if this will have any negative effect on the server that can cause the whole server to stop responding

Comment: yes as i told you above in comment  it will affect and not recommended to do this in production , so make it as a last option , and as I told you first it's recommended to scale up your memory or reduce the load on the machine

Comment: i did not get your point correctly. now one time you mentioned if i minimize the "_minFreeMemoryPercentageToActiveService_" then this will "_it improves system stability by preventing the OutOfMemoryException exceptions,_" .. then on your latest reply you mentioned "_ it will affect and not recommended to do this in production_" .. so will it negatively affect the server or it will improve stability ?? thanks

Comment: as mentioned here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn458357(v=vs.110).aspx it improve stability ? what is the meaning of stability ? instead of you got OutOfMemoryException in case of the web server memory low , you can adjust this value to avoid this exception so the system will be stable as possible , improve stability not mean improve performance ! hope you got it

Answer (score 3):

As Qassas mentioned you have to check the resources on the server.

- check which process is consuming the memory alot
- stop all the services / app pool which are not being used. to free up memory
- if you are not using the Search stop that service as it is biggest consumer of memory all the time.
- dont create too many web application, keep single web application with mutliple site collection.
- How much memory you have ( if it is really less than increase it).
- lastly you can reduce the number 5  if it is your dev machine.
- if you have Anti virus on the server please stop it.

Comment: i have windows 2008 r2 with 4 GB RAM ,, and the database is on different server.. i have one web application with one site collection, and very minimal content as this is a new server..Also i am not sure why you mentioned "_lastly you can reduce the number 5 if it is your dev machine._" so are you trying to say that i should not minimize this on live server ??

Comment: 4 gb ram is not enough, ignore all the response, increase the your ram from 4 GB to 12 GB min. because from 4 gb, 2 will be used by the OS and only 2 GB for SharePoint is not enough. You are lucky enough you are getting the sites with this much ram.

Comment: but can i have a workaround to avoid this error till we get more RAM? now this server we are working on is like a demo server for the custom to do some demos and some users might access it to check the sites... it is not a live is respect that many users will be accessing it  concurrently for their day-to-day work

Comment: upto you, but 4 GB ram will not give assurance that it will all the time. If you working to get more ram till then you can use the workaround....

Comment: yes i already requested to expand the RAM to 8 GB,, but meanwhile you mean to set "minFreeMemoryPercentageToActiveService" to be "2" for example?

Comment: that is correct